# Unruh effect derivation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

I was going through the derivation of the Unruh effect in chapter 5 of [these](https://www.iopb.res.in/%7Eiscqi2011/talks/revisedLecturenotes_fuentes.pdf) lecture notes ("Lecture Series on
Relativistic Quantum Information" by Prof Ivette Fuentes). On p.26 the author introduces the "Unruh basis" and goes on to state that
$$A_k = \int C_{k'} a_{k'} dk'$$
and that
$$A_k = \cosh(r) a^I_k - \sinh(r) a^{II}_k{}^\dagger$$
I'm not entirely sure how these can be derived?

Comment: What is $C_{k'}$?

Comment: @Oбжорoв They are unknown amplitudes.

Comment: @KoutaDagnino I see. This then looks like a Bogolioubov transformation between two bases. Check e.g. Sean Carroll's spacetime and Geometry book.

Comment: I would like to second the suggestion by @Oбжорoв, Carroll's book is a good reference to see this for the first time. The basic idea is that you have on the one hand the Minkowski modes which are the standard plane waves, and the Rindler modes, which are positive-frequency wrt. Rindler observers. One can, however, find another set of positive-frequency modes wrt. inertial observers which have simpler Bogoliubov coefficients when related to Rindler modes. These are the Unruh modes. If I recall correctly Carroll uses them as well to derive the Unruh effect.

Comment: I also heard that Winitzki & Mukhanov have a good treatment of the Unruh effect?

Answer (score 1):

For the computation you need to express the creation and annihilation operators of the Rindler observer in terms of the corresponding operators of an inertial observer. This can be achieved by a Bogolyubov transformation. In this case the Bogolyubov transformation uses the change of coordinates from the inertial to the accelerated observer.

---

I strongly recommend you [these other notes](https://blogs.umass.edu/grqft/files/2015/01/Mukhanov-Winitzki-Unruh-and-Hawking.pdf). As you will see the key point is to use a Bogolyubov transformation for computing the creation $\hat{b}^+_\Omega$ and annihilation $\hat{b}^-_\Omega$ operators associated with the accelerated observer. The expected number of particles for this observer is given by:

$$\langle \hat{N}_\Omega \rangle = \langle 0_M|\hat{b}^+_\Omega\hat{b}^-_\Omega|0_M\rangle = \int_0^\infty \frac{\Omega}{\omega}|F(\omega,\Omega)|^2\text{d}\omega = \frac{1}{e^{2\pi c\Omega/a}-1}\delta(0), \tag{1}$$

where $\delta(0)$ is for the infinite volume of the space, and the function $F(\omega,\Omega)$ is given by:

$$F(\omega,\Omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\text{d}u}{2\pi} \exp\left[i\Omega u + i\frac{c\omega}{a}e^{-au/c}\right], \tag{2}$$

which has the following property:

$$F(\omega,\Omega) = F(-\omega,\Omega) \exp\left(\frac{\pi c\Omega}{a}\right), \qquad a>0, \omega>0, \tag{3}$$

this property allows to compute $(1)$ easily. Then if you compare $(1)$ with the expected Bose-Einstein distribution for massless particles:

$$\frac{\langle \hat{N}_\Omega \rangle}{V} = \frac{1}{e^{E/k_BT}-1}, \tag{4}$$

being $E=\hbar \Omega$ Then you have:

$$\frac{E}{k_BT} = \frac{2\pi c \Omega}{a} \qquad \Rightarrow T = \frac{\hbar a}{2\pi c k_B}$$